# How to use date that is returned from a database in an MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, datetime

So i have written some code that executes an oracle database procedure or function
However, when I run a function I return a varray now i wonder what the mvc application gets from the database (I assume an array because I am using an OParray to execute the function); And how for example i would put these results in a viewbag list

the code that i use to execute the function is as folows

```
OracleParameter[] OPArray1 = new OracleParameter[] { new OracleParameter(null,OracleDbType.Varchar2, 10000, "9a15493038a7365e9ae4c0cfba1136cf", System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input) };
        OracleCommand ODCommand1 = DBCon.StoredProcedureOrFunction("getpresentusers", OPArray1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need just convert to DateTimetype (C#)

Try this:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```